# Modified preorder tree traversal - finding the next node

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, mptt

I have this data:

```
id | parent_id | lft | rgt | name
=====================================
1  | 0         | 1   | 8   | abc
2  | 3         | 5   | 6   | jkl
3  | 1         | 2   | 3   | def
4  | 0         | 9   | 10  | mnno
5  | 1         | 4   | 7   | ghi
```

I need to traverse this hierarchy in this order (ids): 1 > 3 > 5 > 2 > 4

How can I achieve this?

Assume that I want to find the next node of node_x.

```
if (node_x_rgt - node_x_lft == 1) {
    next_node_lft = node_x_rgt + 1;
} else {
    next_node_lft = node_x_lft + 1;
}
```

This formula works only in some cases (node ids 1,3,5,2). The next node of node 2 should be  4.

Comment: Hi, Pondidum. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information you gave all I can advice is to try:

```
select * from table order by id
```

btw, the lft and rgt columns for id 4 are outside of the tree, looks like an error?

btw2, if this is homework, please tag it as such.

**Edit**: version 2 of the question:

These kinds of trees have as invariant that `(lft < rgt)` for all nodes. If the table contains only 1 root node, sequences can be retrieved by either lft or rgt values, in this case lft still does the trick (but the alternative through rgt in descending order won't):

```
select * from table order by lft
```

Comment: Thanks rsp. Actually, yes id 4 is a separate tree. Id 2 is the last node of tree of node id 1. If I request the next node of id 2, it should give me the first nod of next tree (tree of node id 4).

Comment: How ordering by id can help me? And also this is not a homework :)

Comment: Ordering by id helped in the 1st version of the question where the requested order was 1,2,3,4,5 :-)

Comment: yes, i think this solves the "next node" problem. But as you have said "...but the alternative through rgt in descending order won't...", this doesn't work for finding previous node, right?

Comment: rsp, how about if i put all trees under one root node?

Comment: rsp, forget about the previous node question. noticed that i can use the same lft ordering to retrieve the previous node.

Comment: for future reference, to find next node: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE lft > %s ORDER BY `lft` ASC LIMIT 1" and to find previous node "SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE lft < %s ORDER BY `lft` DESC LIMIT 1" where %s is the node that next and previous node to be found. Thanks rsp.